# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined of a signup page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I built a sign up page for my web app using react, here is the code:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import app from "../base";

const SignUp = ({ history }) => {
  const handleSignUp = useCallback(
    async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
      try {
        await app
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
        history.push("/");
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    },
    [history]
  );

  const [firstName, setFirstname] = useState('');

  const handleFirstNameInput = e => {
    setFirstname(e.target.current.value);
  };
  
  const logName = () => {
    alert(firstName);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen">
      <form
        className="w-full max-w-lg m-auto border-solid border-4 border-gray-600 p-6 rounded-lg"
        onSubmit={handleSignUp}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3">
          {/* Div for first name field */}
          <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
            <label
              className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
              htmlFor="grid-first-name"
            >
              First Name
            </label>
            <input
              className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
              id="grid-first-name"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Ramon"
              onChange={handleFirstNameInput}
              value={firstName}
            />
          </div>
          {/* Div for last name */}
          <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
            <label
              className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
              htmlFor="grid-last-name"
            >
              Last Name
            </label>
            <input
              className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-last-name"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Wenzel"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
          {/* Div for email */}
          <div className="w-full px-3">
            <label
              className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
              htmlFor="grid-password"
            >
              Email
            </label>
            <input
              className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-email"
              type="email"
              placeholder="123@example.com"
            />
          </div>

          {/* Div for password */}
          <div className="w-full px-3">
            <label
              className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
              htmlFor="grid-password"
            >
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="grid-password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="******************"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="md:flex md:items-center">
          {/* Submit Button */}
          <button
            className="shadow bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-400 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            type="submit"
            onClick={logName}
          >
            Sign Up
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(SignUp);
```

however I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

Does anyone have any ideas pls help me with this!

Also, I'm trying to get the first name of user here and put it into my home.js(homepage), how to export the first name here and put it into another js file?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
setFirstname(e.target.current.value)
```

to

```
setFirstname(e.target.value)
```

There is no `current` property on `event.target`.

You might have confused with `event.currentTarget`. But that's a bit different.

You could check the difference between `event.currentTarget` and `event.target` here -> https://joequery.me/code/event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-30-seconds/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I changed it to e.target.value but it still gives me the TypeError message

Comment: Check this -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ndcbnh